# grid-column-gap adds gap at the end of the last div in the row

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

I've been experimenting with grids in css and come across the following.
I have created a container containing several `div`s

My `.container` creates a grid of 5 items having a width of 20%.

I added the `grid-column-gap` and noticed that it created a overflow in the container. I found that the `grid-column-gap` adds it's value to the `grid-template-columns` value. So I changed the value it 19%.

Now the items fit the grid. However my understanding is that `grid-column-gap` is added between the `div`s. What I'm having right now is that the last item also contains a gap at the right side.

I want to have the gaps between the `div`s and not at the end.
Please, see the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mp91pk6c/)

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `5 * 19%` (your columns) + `4 * 1%` (your column gaps) = 99%. The remaining space (1%) is what you're seeing on the right side. It's not `grid-column-gap` space. It's just remaining space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Percentage units on `grid` are calculated as any other. If your unit is percentage it will add extra space to whole calculated area.

If however you add `fr` unit it will work similarly like flexbox and it will not add extra space.

Comment: That indeed did the trick. Thnx

Comment: This is very good to know, thanks!